# How do enable vim's 'd-space' key binding to delete a character?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I'm using the vim extension in Visual Studio Code and most everything works as I would expect. However, 'd-[space]' does not delete a character as it does in vim. How does one enable that?

Comment: why wouldn't you just use `x`?

Comment: I suppose I could, my fingers are just used to the d-space sequence. I'll retrain them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
noremap d<space> dl    " to answer your specific question
onoremap <space> l     " for other operation like change or yank
```

But `x` is one keystrike so better use it.